# How to put Java program online?

Tags: java, sockets, host

I am learning Java and am trying to do some experiments with networking Java programs.

I have a program made in 2 parts with a client and a server and it works in local testing but the program actually has usefulness for me and a friend of mine and I want to put the server online so both of us can connect to it and use it.

Where/How can I put the program online and have it running so that the client programs can connect to the ServerSocket with an ip address? (Preferably free)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I cannot believe that someone hasn't set up a free developer server for people just wanting to test programs on the small scale. The resources/bandwidth needed to test programs like mine would be minimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you dont want to pay server hosting then I would open a virtual server on my computer, then playaround with modem and forward related port to server ip. I would use a port more than 40000. Then just send your ip and port your friend or update application.

Comment: I concur. This is the easiest and cheapest way to do what you want to do - especially if your program is only going to be used between you and your friends. By cheapest, I mean the only way that you are going to do this freely. Otherwise, you need a web host that supports Java - and as far as I am aware, such a free service is non existent unfortunately...

Answer (score 4):

If you really want the application to go live within 5 mins, try [Jelastic](http://jelastic.com). If you have built a WAR file, simply sign up with their server,choose a provider closest to your geo location, configure Tomcat and you can upload the WAR file through their fantastic web console. Otherwise if you have some source control system(SVN,GIT etc), you just connect and build it with their Maven console and you can be ready. I used it for my start up([Cloudlabz](http://cloudlabz.in)) and really found it exciting.

Surya

Answer (score 2):

You could also consider the cheapest Rackspace Cloud Server. You'll get a full fledged Linux server (distribution of your choice) for about USD 11/month. I've done that now and then myself to try things out.

Just install Java on it and you're good to go.

http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/cloud_hosting_products/servers/pricing/

Answer (score 1):

http://ideone.com/

is that what you want for this?

This is a free web app for you to run your program online....so you can just paste your code and run it.

Comment: That doesn't allow network connections and it limits the runtime of the application to just a few seconds.  I'm not sure how that answers the question even remotely.

Answer (score 1):

On the cloud you could use two different services in order to host your Java application.

1. IaaS (Infrastructure as a Service). Where you can just rent a specific infrastructure on the cloud and you could install and configure all the services that you need.
2. PaaS (Platform as a Service). In this case, you still enjoy the infrastructure on the cloud + the service Aaren full pre-configured. It means that you can deploy your application without installing or configuring anything. You just need to deploy your application. You have an example about how it works [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lKGXff0jjWw). Also, you usually can test your Java apps on the cloud without paying.

Answer (score 0):

You should host the server in Heroku ,they offer a free hosting with limits , I have an app there